# mixing TextField and Text

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, textfield

I want to make like this view, any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: where is the textField ?

Comment: " this :yellow;

Comment: You mean spanable : https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Comment: no not this I need to insert textfield between text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution by using [WidgetSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetSpan-class.html)

so the solution is like this:

[image: code preview]

```dart
Text.rich(
                    TextSpan(
                      children: <InlineSpan>[
                        TextSpan(text: '<body ',style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                        TextSpan(text: 'style=\n"',style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.teal,
                            fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                        WidgetSpan(
                          child: SizedBox(
                              width: 30,
                              height: 30,
                              child: TextField()
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(text: ':yellow;',style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                        TextSpan(text: '\nbackground-color:',style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.purple,
                            fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                        TextSpan(text: 'black;',style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                        TextSpan(text: '">',style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.teal,
                            fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                        TextSpan(text: '\nhi :)',style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                        TextSpan(text: '\n</',style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                        WidgetSpan(
                          child: SizedBox(
                              width: 30,
                              height: 30,
                              child: TextField()
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(text: '>',style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 24
                        ),),
                      ],
                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just this view with a `TextField`, you might wanna consider two things:

> 1. [Column class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) for maintaining the items in the next line
> 2. [Row class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) for continuing the items horizontally

Here is the code:

**Please note:** `TextField` is working. So you can use it, but do read about the usage. It is just used for representation, but you might wanna use `TextEditingController` for that, if you want to capture the data in the `TextField`

```dart
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // top layer
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("<body", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900])),
                SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                Text("style", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.greenAccent)),
                Text("=", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ]
            ),
            
            // Middle layer, for next line
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("''", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
                SizedBox(width: 80.0, child: TextField()), // this is textfield
                Text(":yellow;", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ]
            ),
            
            // Middle layer part 2, for next line
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("background-color:", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo)),
                Text("black;", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                Text("''>", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange))
              ]
            ),
            
            // for next line
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("hi :)", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]))
              ]
            ),
            
            // last line
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("</___________>", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]))
              ]
            ),
          ]
        )
```

This might be long for you, but this will serve your purpose like in the result.

[image: Resultant image]

Comment: Yeah, I know how do it manually, Is there any solution that automate this view?
or how to do it based on text for example: "<h1></*h1*>" iwant to replace between "*" with textfield

Comment: For this have a string variable which comes between `"*"`, and replace it with the inputs. `Text("$my_variable")` @ramzieus

Comment: how to put widget inside text?